# InvalidBasesError when running migrate in Django

Tags: django, django-cms, django-migrations

I'm trying to discover django-cms.

I've made a fresh project (following [these steps](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/support-3.0.x/how_to/install.html)). But when I do a `django migrate`, I get the following issue:

```
>>>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: treebeard, menus, sekizai, cms, djangocms_admin_style
  Apply all migrations: sessions, reversion, auth, admin, contenttypes, sites, djangocms_picture
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
  Installing custom SQL...
  Installing indexes...
Running migrations:
  Applying djangocms_picture.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/vmonteco/.Envs/django-cms/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/vmonteco/.Envs/django-cms/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/vmonteco/.Envs/django-cms/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/vmonteco/.Envs/django-cms/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/vmonteco/.Envs/django-cms/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 161, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "/home/vmonteco/.Envs/django-cms/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 68, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "/home/vmonteco/.Envs/django-cms/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 96, in apply_migration
    if self.detect_soft_applied(migration):
  File "/home/vmonteco/.Envs/django-cms/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 140, in detect_soft_applied
    apps = project_state.render()
  File "/home/vmonteco/.Envs/django-cms/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 75, in render
    "for more" % new_unrendered_models
django.db.migrations.state.InvalidBasesError: Cannot resolve bases for [<ModelState: 'cms.PageUser'>, <ModelState: 'cms.PageUserGroup'>]
This can happen if you are inheriting models from an app with migrations (e.g. contrib.auth)
 in an app with no migrations; see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#dependencies for more
```

Here is my INSTALLED_APPS :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'djangocms_admin_style', # for the admin skin. must be before 'django.contrib.admin'                             
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'cms', # django CMS itself                                                                                       
    'treebeard', # utilities for implementing a tree (replaces mptt)                                                 
    'menus', # helper for model independent herarchical website navigation                                           
    'sekizai', # for JS and CSS management.                                                                          
    'reversion', # to versionize content                                                                             
    #'djangocms_file',                                                                                               
    #'djangocms_picture',
    #'djangocms_video',                                                                                              
    #'djangocms_link',                                                                                               
    #'djangocms_text_ckeditor', # django text plugin                                                                 
)
```

This error occurs when I uncomment one of the last lines. Why?
How could I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/3513#issuecomment-98353642).

You have to change `MIGRATION_MODULES` in your project settings, removing `_django` from some of the values. The linked page mentions `cms` and `menus`, but I had to remove it from `djangocms_link` and `djangocms_text_ckeditor` too.